# save operation in jpa data repository doesn't work when define mutiple @EnableJpaRepositories classes

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am researching on usage of Spring Data JPA. Appreciated if can help check where is wrong.

I created 2 JPA repositories: `APIRepository` and `ClientRepository` in 2 different packages and also created 2 configuration classes to configure these 2 repositories using `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation respectively.

When a Spring application calls these 2 repositories' `save()` methods at the same time, the `APIRepository.save()` will fail, but without exception. If move `@Primiary` annotation (this is to avoid `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`) to `APIAppConfig` class, `ClientRepository.save` will fail without exception. I opened SQL log, no update SQL was executed for failing method.

did anyone hit such a situation? how to use Spring Data Jpa?

*`APIRepository`*

```
package test.api;

public interface APIRepository extends Repository<API, Long>{
 ....
}
```

*`APIAppConfig`*

```
package test.api;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.api")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "test.api.repository", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "apiEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef="apiTransactionManager",
        enableDefaultTransactions=true
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class APIAppConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean apiEntityManagerFactory(){
     ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager apiTransactionManager() {
    ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource apiDataSource() {
    ...
    }
}
```

*`APIService`*

```
package test.api;

@Service
public class APIService {

    @Autowired
    private APIRepository apiRepository;


    public API findOne(Long id){
        return apiRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Transactional("apiTransactionManager")
    public void updateOne(API api){
        apiRepository.save(api);
    }
}
```

*`ClientRepository`*

```
package test.client;

public interface  ClientRepository extends Repository<Client, Long>{
   ...
}
```

*`ClientAppConfig`*

```
package test.client;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "test.client")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "test.client",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef="transactionManager",
        enableDefaultTransactions=true
)

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ClientAppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
       ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
     ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    ...
    }
}
```

*`ClientService`*

```
package test.client;

@Service
public class ClientService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;


    public DaoTest findOne(Long id){
        return clientRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public void updateOne(Client client){
        clientRepository.save(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you  call a repository when you get an `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`? This should happen during creation of the ApplicationContext and should end you with nor repositories, nor services. Somthing is missing in this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `APIAppConfig` class you have set

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "test.api.repository",
```

But your `APIRepository` is in the package `test.api` and not in `test.api.repository`, at least as I can see in your `APIRepository` class source code.

So either change the `basePackages` value to reflect the correct one, or move your `APIRepository` inside the `test.api.repository` package